# Regex expression to extract title from PDF in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am reading PDF using textract. Inside of PDF, there are some titles in it. Some examples are:

- 5\n\n A
- 5.1\n\n A B
- 5.1.1\n\n A B
- 5.1.1\n\n A/ B ()

In general:

> (numeric digit) then: (two times \n) then: (words containing alpha
>   numeric digit in random number of times) and finally a line break

Please noted that, I exactly post the string as I get output after reading using textract.Moreover, hence these are titles therefore, after a line break the paragraph begins. At present, i just want to extract titles from PDF.

Input Text(For example purpose:):

1 Human being

Human being are ....

1.1 People from Asia/Europe

............

1.1.1 Man from Asia/Europe

.........

Output:

1 Human being

1.1 People from Asia/Europe

1.1.1 Man from Asia/Europe

Any help/suggestion is welcome. And it would be really appreciable if an explanation is given for the regex expression.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: What part of the string do you want to extract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s an example that will work:

```
(\d.?\ ?)*\n\n[A-Za-z0-9 \/]+\n
```

Try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/gGg2yG/1).

Example python 3 usage:

```
import re

regex = r"(\d.?\ ?)*\n\n[A-Za-z0-9 \/]+\n"

test_str = ("1 \n\n"
    "Human being\n\n"
    "Human being are ....\n\n"
    "1.1 \n\n"
    "People from Asia/Europe\n\n"
    "............\n\n"
    "1.1.1 \n\n"
    "Man from Asia/Europe\n\n"
    ".........")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```